# WCF routing and various endpoints

Tags: wcf, routes, wcf-routing

I have a little problem and don't know where to start.

I need to make a subscribtion service and if returns unique address on which consumer will send soaps after subscription. It works like so : you send a SOAP on address http://foo.org/Subscribe and in response you get address http://foo.org/SubscriptionManager/1, the next consumer will get http://foo.org/SubscriptionManager/2 etc.

How can i emplement that via WCF? I guesed that WCF have something like ASP.Net Routing, where i could route links like  http://foo.org/SubscriptionManager/ and access 2 as a parameter, but i haven't found something like that.

I look forward to any help.

Comment: are you asking how to implement a WCF client that can send a request to an endpoint, and have it return an address as a response?

Answer (score 2):

The question I have is why do you want to route users to different endpoints?

The whole idea of returning a service URI for the consumer to call is not good design in my opinion.

You are forcing your consumers to do more work - they must make an extra call and interrogate the response just to find out which endpoint they have to call.

If your requirement is to spread load between two services you should offer a single load-balanced endpoint which will then send requests to the other endpoints.

Alternatively, if your requirement is to route certain users to one or other of the subscription services based on some rules then you can have a look at [WCF-Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx).

Comment: Well, the idea is in subscriptions, it is our companys specification and so i Have to do it in such a way. I haven't found on MSDN how can i generate Endpoint like http://foo.org/SubscriptionManager/1 in runtime and return it to my consumer. The best solution is if i could make a filter, which will route my consumers to service operation with a parameter, as i said in my question.

Comment: WCF-Routing allows your to create filters to route service requests based on the content of the request messages. However, changing the soap requests in-flight is trickier. I think WCF Routing provides this, in something called *SOAP Processing* (half way down this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517422.aspx)

Comment: Hugh, thanks a lot for help. Sorry, i'm newbie, so i cannot vote you up for help. The last question i have - does WCF supports runtime-creation of Endpoints so that i don't need to work with routing(sorry, SOAP-Processing did not give me a solution, i'm afraid, i'll need to work with Http headers to route messages)?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you before. WCF does support the runtime creation of endpoints yes.